# NGINX proxy config issues

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, gunicorn, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a web app currently running on port 8000 and recently got an SSL certificate. I've installed nginx and attempted to have all port 80 and 443 traffic redirected to port 8000 on the local system.

Here is where I am at:

- Browsing to the server on port 8000 still works and renders with no issue
- Browsing to the server on port 80 renders a very watered down version of the page (almost like there is a permission issue to other parts of the app including images)... NOTE: it doesn't auto render the page on 443 (as it should)
- Browsing to the server on port 443 renders the same results as browsing on port 80

Below is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name my-webapp.com www.my-webapp.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my-webapp.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my-webapp.com/privkey.pem;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/

    location / {

    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }}
```

I am literally at a lost, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what back-end technology you are using, but here is a useful article on how to configure nginx as reverse proxy for ASP.NET Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?tabs=aspnetcore2x The nginx.conf example at the bottom may be of help.

Comment: Thanks. I am on Ubuntu 14 but I'll check it out.

Comment: When you say "watered down" that suggests that your CSS isn't being loaded perhaps, and neither your images? A common way to confgure nginx is to use a separate location block for your static files (CSS, images, etc), so requests for these files are not proxied to gunicorn, but are loaded direct from the disk by nginx. It's more efficient, as there is normally no need for your app server, gunicorn, to be handling these types of file. Are your static files stored in a place that is accessible to nginx? E.g. a "/static" folder inside the main app?